# Function returns null value

Tags: swift, function, return-value

This might be a basic question but I am unable to figure this out. My function always returns a null value and I am not sure why.

My main code ( in a different view controller) calls this function with a "string" to search. But at the end of the function, I can never return the results. If i print the search results where I have the final print statement, then I do see the results. But right after that function is complete, the return value is nil. How would I get the return value from this function ? Thanks in advance,. I am using Swift btw.

```
 func fetchSearchResults (_ searchString: String) -> Array<Any> {
        self.globalPost = [Posts]()
        self.postKeysArray = []
        var searchIndex:AlgoliaSearch.Index
        let query = Query()
        searchIndex = self.client.index(withName: "Comments")
```

// you can ignore all of this below until the last couple lines...

```
        query.attributesToRetrieve = ["userComment","postId"]
        query.attributesToHighlight = ["postId"]
        query.query = searchString
        query.optionalWords = [searchString]

        let curSearchId = searchId

        searchIndex.search(query, completionHandler: { (content, error) in
            if (curSearchId <= self.displayedSearchId) || (error != nil) {
                return // Newest query already displayed or error
            }
            self.displayedSearchId = curSearchId
            self.loadedPage = 0 // Reset loaded page

            guard let hits = content!["hits"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else { return }
            var tmp = [String]()

            for hit in hits {
                //                print ("Comment is \(commentRecord(json:hit).postId)")
                tmp.append(commentRecord(json:hit).postId!)
            }
            self.postKeysArray = tmp
            self.getDatafromFirebase(searchString)
```

// so my search code returns some values here and i see them in the post keysArray.

```
            print ("Search Results -post keys is \(self.postKeysArray)")  \\ returns correct values here in the Array
        })
        self.searchId += 1
```

// But here i get a NULL value.

```
        return self.postKeysArray \\ returns empty array

    }
```

Comment: When you say "null," do you mean `nil` or an empty array?  If it's the latter, that's because it's returning before the completion handler finishes.

Comment: Its an empty array but i do get the results for the print inside the completion handler.

Comment: @SBCoder There's nothing "null" about an empty array.

Comment: @SBCoder It's empty because you're returning the array prior to the competition handler being done adding to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexander noted, you are printing the search results inside the completion handler, which has not executed yet when `fetchSearchResults` returns. There are a couple different ways that you could solve this. One would be to refactor `fetchSearchResults` to take a closure:

```
func fetchSearchResults (_ searchString: String, completionHandler completion: (Array<Any>) -> ()) {
    // ...
    searchIndex.search(query, completionHandler: { (content, error) in
        // ...
        self.postKeysArray = tmp
        self.getDatafromFirebase(searchString)
        // so my search code returns some values here and i see them in the post keysArray.

        print ("Search Results -post keys is \(self.postKeysArray)")  \\ returns correct values here in the Array
        completion(self.postKeysArray)
    })
}
```

Then, in your 'main code', wherever you were calling:

```
let results = searchController.fetchSearchResults(searchString)
doSomething(with: results)
```

You would now have:

```
searchController.fetchSearchResults(searchString, { results in
    doSomething(results)
})
```

This line could also be written:

```
searchController.fetchSearchResults(searchString, doSomething)
```

If you really can't have fetchSearchResults be asynchronous, then you could use `DispatchSemaphore` to wait until the completion handler has finished:

```
func fetchSearchResults (_ searchString: String) -> Array<Any> {
    // ...
    var semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(0)
    searchIndex.search(query, completionHandler: { (content, error) in
        // ...
        self.postKeysArray = tmp
        self.getDatafromFirebase(searchString)
        // so my search code returns some values here and i see them in the post keysArray.

        print ("Search Results -post keys is \(self.postKeysArray)")  \\ returns correct values here in the Array
        semaphore.signal()
    })
    semaphore.wait()
    return self.postKeysArray
}
```

Note that unless you know what you're doing, using semaphores is *not* a good idea. If you don't know what threads various callbacks might be called on, it can lead to a deadlock. The above example will not work if the `searchIndex.search` completion handler is called on the same `DispatchQueue` as `fetchSearchResults`. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, you probably shouldn't do it. It will almost certainly be better to use asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I got it working with your recommended code. Need to take some time to understand it but thanks much again. Btw, is there an email/twitter I could reach you at ?

Comment: I should have an email available on my GitHub @jumhyn.